# Pandas: how to sort dataframe by column AND by index

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

Given the DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([6, 4, 2, 4, 5], index=[2, 6, 3, 4, 5], columns=['A'])
```

Results in:

```
   A
2  6
6  4
3  2
4  4
5  5
```

Now, I would like to sort by values of Column A AND the index.

e.g.

```
df.sort_values(by='A')
```

Returns

```
   A
3  2
6  4
4  4
5  5
2  6
```

Whereas I would like

```
   A
3  2
4  4
6  4
5  5
2  6
```

How can I get a sort on the column first and index second?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `lexsort` from numpy may be other way and little faster as well:

```
df.iloc[np.lexsort((df.index, df.A.values))] # Sort by A.values, then by index
```

Result:

```
   A
3  2
4  4
6  4
5  5
2  6
```

Comparing with `timeit`:

```
%%timeit
df.iloc[np.lexsort((df.index, df.A.values))] # Sort by A.values, then by index
```

Result:

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 278 µs per loop
```

With reset index and set index again:

```
 %%timeit
df.reset_index().sort_values(by=['A','index']).set_index('index')
```

Result:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 2.09 ms per loop
```

Comment: How would one do this for a multi index dataframe?

Answer (score 13):

You can sort by index and then by column A using `kind='mergesort'`.

This works because [mergesort is stable](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html).

```
res = df.sort_index().sort_values('A', kind='mergesort')
```

Result:

```
   A
3  2
4  4
6  4
5  5
2  6
```

Comment: looks like `lexsort` from `numpy` is little faster than `mergesort`.

Comment: I agree, I think this solution is more easy to read. +1 Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are great. I'll throw in one other option, which is to provide a name for the index first using [rename_axis](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and then reference it in `sort_values`. I have not tested the performance but expect the accepted answer to still be faster.

`df.rename_axis('idx').sort_values(by=['A', 'idx'])`

```
     A
idx   
3    2
4    4
6    4
5    5
2    6
```

You can clear the index name afterward if you want with `df.index.name = None`.